# In a web site, Where do you declare project-scope enums?

Tags: enums, scoping

In an asp.net web site project, Where do you declare project-scope enums ?

Comment: what environment are you developing in?

Comment: which language are you using and which type project

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your enum global, then you declare it in application-level module.